# Retrieving relationships with SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx

When using sfdx to retrieve metadata, is there a way to retrieve the relationships between objects?
For instance get a file pertaining to Object1 which mentions that the field Field1 is taken from Field27 in Object2?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an API solution, but a SOQL solution:
For an object's outbound relationships, we can use the following SOQL query:

```
select QualifiedApiName, Description, 
            DataType, DeveloperName, RelationshipName 
            from FieldDefinition 
            where EntityDefinition.DeveloperName='<object_name>' and 
              RelationshipName <> '' 
            order by DataType
```

For inbound relationships:

```
select QualifiedApiName, DataType, DeveloperName, RelationshipName, EntityDefinition.DeveloperName 
                            from FieldDefinition 
                            where EntityDefinition.DeveloperName <> ''  and
                              RelationshipName <> '' and 
                              DataType = 'Lookup({object_name})' 
                            order by DataType
```